# Different solutions for floating a DIY torii gate deeper than it's original floating level

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, water, buoyancy

I'm facing a dead end with my physics experience on a new build I am working on. Any help would be appreciated.

Basic problem:

I am trying to build a floating wooden [Torii gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torii) to be placed on water in a way that the structure's original floating level is pulled/pushed downwards in some way - Maybe 15-30 cm below surface.

Reasons for a build like this:

1) It can't be there all year due to weather conditions

2) I want to go through it with my kayak

3) It's flipping cool!

Questions:

A) How can I achieve a STABLEish structure floating under water surface? I guess the best way would be to somehow pull it downwards with weights? How would YOU do it?

B) How can this be calculated?

C) Tips, tricks?

Ask questions too.

[image: Mockup image]

Answer (score 0):

You want it to still float, but at a lower level?  Add a dense material to the bottom or near the bottom of the structure in a symmetrical way.  Perhaps a heavy metal chain around the perimeter of the structure at the base.  If you had a long chain, you could make the depth adjustable by changing how many times the chain is wound around the structure, if the excess amount rests on the bottom of the body of water.

Comment: Yes, floating at a lower level. That sounds like a reasonable solution!